# Break text on spaces in documentation remarks

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

It appears text in the Remarks section of a Documentation topic wraps in the middle of words. Take the following example:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/1337/compilation#t=201608100830251691321

[image]

Comment: Something bad happenned to **all** tables, not just in the Remarks section.

Comment: A fix is on the way.

Comment: Judging by the url, this topic is so 1337 that it broke words apart.

Comment: I'm ignoring this issue because the circles aren't freehanded.